# Titration of butyllithium methodology

Tags: organic-chemistry, titration

I am a physical chemist with limited experience in organic work. I am going to be using butyllithium for insertion of lithium into a metal oxide structure (Cava, Solid State Ionics, 1983). One goal is to determine the amount of butyllithium consumed during the reaction. Cava uses "acid-base titration", but does not go deeper into the detail of what that entails. My assumption is that I quench the BuLi with 2-propanol, and then titrate the new organolithium compound outside of the glovebox with just a typical HCl or something. But my experience in this department is very limited.

Do any of you organic folks know the best way to go about doing this? This work will be performed inside of an argon glovebox.

Thank you.